# What is the good way to add filter programmatically to dc.js based charts?

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have two charts created through dc.js and I've been trying to add a filter like that :

```
chart['hour'].filter([0, 16]);
dc.redrawAll();
```

Unfortunately, the other chart is not properly updated, as if the subset of data was empty.

[image: Charts, once filtered]

You'll find a fiddle with the issue there: http://jsfiddle.net/lolcat/ep8wjkee/

Any hint would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: It depends on the type of filter, but this one is particularly tricky because it depends on the type of scale. Flagging as duplicate; just comment if it doesn't work for you!

Comment: Using dc.filters.RangedFilter did the trick. Thanks Gordon !